# cant make heads or tails of this HW assignment, can someone help? [C]

Tags: c, computer-science

i need some help with my hw, need to do this for tomorrow. had to link to paste bin becuase the formatting on this website did not look right.
http://pastebin.com/YA6PtHyB#

EDIT: I would like to know how i go about doing this assignment, or how the assignment is done, as frankly i cant understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assignment is to write functions to examine and edit floating-point numbers, specifically single-precision floats.

So you should first understand floats.  Presumably this was covered in your class, but you can read up on them here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Then you need to use bit masking and shifting to do the editing parts.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html